# Passing bash variables to a script?

Tags: python, bash

What's the best way to pass bash variables to a python script.  I'd like to do something like the following:

```bash
$cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

foo="hi"
python -c 'import test; test.printfoo($foo)'

$cat test.py
#!/bin/python

def printfoo(str):
    print str
```

When I try running the bash script, I get a syntax error:

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    import test; test.printfoo($foo)
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short, this works:

```
...
python -c "import test; test.printfoo('$foo')"
...
```

**Update:**

If you think the string may contain single quotes(`'`) as said by @Gordon in the comment below, You can escape those single quotes pretty easily in bash. Here's a alternative solution in that case:

```
...
python -c "import test; test.printfoo('"${foo//\'/\\\'}"');"
...
```

Comment: This will fail interestingly if $foo contains any single-quotes or other characters python interprets inside literals.  @Adam's solution is more robust...

Answer (score 14):

You can use [`os.getenv`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.getenv) to access environment variables from Python:

```
import os
import test
test.printfoo(os.getenv('foo'))
```

However, in order for environment variables to be passed from Bash to any processes it creates, you need to export them with the [`export` builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins):

```
foo="hi"
export foo
# Alternatively, the above can be done in one line like this:
# export foo="hi"

python <<EOF
import os
import test
test.printfoo(os.getenv('foo'))
EOF
```

As an alternative to using environment variables, you can just pass parameters directly on the command line.  Any options passed to Python after the `-c command` get loaded into the `sys.argv` array:

```
# Pass two arguments 'foo' and 'bar' to Python
python - foo bar <<EOF
import sys
# argv[0] is the name of the program, so ignore it
print 'Arguments:', ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
# Output is:
# Arguments: foo bar
EOF
```

Answer (score 3):

Do it with argv handling. This way you don't have to import it then run it from the interpreter.

test.py

```
import sys

def printfoo(string):
    print string

if __name__ in '__main__':
    printfoo(sys.argv[1])

python test.py testingout
```

Comment: I was hoping to call printfoo directly because I have a lot of other python functions that take arguments, which need to be called from bash.  If I go through main for all of them, it would be more complex.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use double quotes to get variable substitution in bash. Similar to PHP.

```
$ foo=bar
$ echo $foo
bar
$ echo "$foo"
bar
$ echo '$foo'
$foo
```

Thus, this should work:

```
python -c "import test; test.printfoo($foo)"
```

Comment: That gets further, but now there's an error on the python side, where it says NameError: name 'hi' is not defined.

Comment: Can't edit, but for anyone looking at this and the comment above me, the answer is to put $foo in single quotes in the python segment, since otherwise it'll just be read as undefined variable name bar, hence the NameError. So `python -c "import test; test.printfoo('$foo')"`, now you'll be printing the string 'bar' as desired.